# put some column values in a new column using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
user_id    workplace
1          Microsoft
1          Google
2          eBay
3          Panadora
3          Netflix
```

What I want is to have a table like this:

```
user_id   places_worked
1        Microsoft,Google
2        eBay
3        Panadora,Netflix
```

Is there anyway in SQL that can do this?

Comment: Check out group_concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use group by with group concat operation

SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(workplace)
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY user_id;

check following example

```
select * from payments;
+----+------------+---------+-------+
| id | date       | user_id | value |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |    10 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |       3 |    15 |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |       4 |    20 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   100 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   150 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


select c.user_id,group_concat(p.value) from calls c inner join payments p on p.user_id=c.user_id group by c.user_id;
+---------+-----------------------+
| user_id | group_concat(p.value) |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       1 | 10,150,10,150,10,150  |
|       2 | 100                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you know why this makes the query so slow? I want to use this group_concat()  with a join to another table and it is VERY slow. almost not running!

Comment: can you execute show index statement for that table and give the result

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jarlh you could do this using group_concat

```
 SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(workplace)
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY user_id;
```